# Subsetting a 4D array into train and test splits

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4D array containing the details of 5500 images (350x350 pixels in size - each entry contains the RBG value of an individual pixel), along with a 1d array that assigns a value to each of these:

```
>>> np.array(images).shape
(5500, 350, 350, 3)
>>> np.array(labels).shape
(5500,)
```

I want to subset both the `images` and `labels` array into 80% train and 20% test splits. I've done this with the `labels` array without any issues:

```
>>> indices = np.random.permutation(5500)
>>> training_idx, test_idx = indices[:4400], indices[4400:]
>>> training_idx
array([1209, 1958, 3376, ..., 1875,   55, 5408])
>>> labels_train, labels_test = labels[training_idx], labels[test_idx]
>>> labels_train
array([1.7     , 3.833333, 2.333333, ..., 2.016667, 3.15    , 4.316667])
```

However, trying to make a `images_train` for example (subsetting the `images` 4D array into 80% of its values) is giving me issues. I've tried for example the following:

```
images_train, images_test = images[training_idx][:,][:,][:,], images[test_idx][:,][:,][:,]
images_train, images_test = images[training_idx,:,:,:,], images[test_idx,:,:,:,]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `sklearn` Method:

Although it's not pure `numpy`, I would suggest looking into [`train_test_split` from sklearn.model_selection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), as it does basically exactly what you're trying to do, but in an easy way:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

images_train, images_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.2)
```

## `numpy` method:

You could also just do this in `numpy`, but the code is less clear:

**Generalizable code for an 80/20 split:**

```
indices = np.random.permutation(len(images))

images_train, images_test = images[indices[:int(len(images)*0.8)]], images[indices[int(len(images)*0.8):]]

labels_train, labels_test = labels[indices[:int(len(images)*0.8)]], labels[indices[int(len(images)*0.8):]]
```

**Using your hard-coded train / test sizes:**

```
indices = np.random.permutation(5500)

images_train, images_test = images[indices[:4400]], images[indices[4400:]]

labels_train, labels_test = labels[indices[:4400]], labels[indices[4400:]]
```